# Javascript Count Up In Three Minute Intervals

Tags: javascript

Found a JS Count Up Timer [here](https://guwii.com/bytes/count-date-time-javascript/) Is there anyway I can make the minutes increase by three every three minutes? instead of the minutes counting by one? Been messing with it but I seem to break it everytime

```
> window.onload = function() {
  // Month Day, Year Hour:Minute:Second, id-of-element-container
  countUpFromTime("Dec 23, 2020 12:00", 'countup1'); // ****** Change this line!
};


function countUpFromTime(countFrom, id) {
  countFrom = new Date(countFrom).getTime();
  var now = new Date(),
      countFrom = new Date(countFrom),
      timeDifference = (now - countFrom);
    
  var secondsInADay = 60 * 60 * 1000 * 24,
      secondsInAHour = 60 * 60 * 1000;
    
  days = Math.floor(timeDifference / (secondsInADay) * 1);
  hours = Math.floor((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) / (secondsInAHour) * 1);
  mins = Math.floor(((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) % (secondsInAHour)) / (60 * 1000) * 1);

  var idEl = document.getElementById(id);
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('days')[0].innerHTML = days;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('hours')[0].innerHTML = hours;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('minutes')[0].innerHTML = mins;

  clearTimeout(countUpFromTime.interval);
  countUpFromTime.interval = setTimeout(function(){ countUpFromTime(countFrom, id); }, 1000);
    

}
```

Comment: `clearTimeout(countUpFromTime.interval);` how `interval` can be a prop of `countUpFromTime` ?

Comment: don't use seTimeOut(), prefer to use setInterval()

Comment: I might have worded this a little weird, instead of the minutes going up by one every minute, I want it to go up by three every three minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setInterval(functionToCall, 180000)` method.

And pass the function which you use to increase the count. This will call that for every 180000 milliseconds(3 minutes).

[See the reference for more details](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)